# Phantom.js fill fields,click submit, and now stuck at accessing the next page

Tags: node.js, javascript, phantomjs

I've start with phantom.js (btw I'm in love). I'm trying to make the headless browser go to my php admin panel, log in with a username and password, and from the page that it redirects to after log in i want to get some text from a div tag.

So far I manage to successfully fill the fields, create a click event, and even find the access to the DOM part of the div tag and get the inner.Text.

The only missing part for me is what to do when phantom.js clicks on a button (the log in button in this case) which will log me in and change the page content. I can't find how to handle after .click(); event.

This is the code I made so far (by the way its a good way to start with...)

```
var page = new WebPage();

page.open("the url comes here",
function(status){
if(status != "success"){console.log('fail loading the page');}
    page.evaluate(function(){
        var arr = document.getElementsByName("formname");
        arr[0].elements["username"].value="username here";
        arr[0].elements["password"].value="password here";
    arr[0].elements["submit"].click();
        return;
    }
    phantom.exit()
});
```

The code i want run on the page that comes after it is

```
console.log(window.frames[1].document.getElementById('status').innerHTML)
```

So the only question remaining is how to handle the redirect and launch the script on the other page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a new callback for the page load:

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(status){
  console.log(window.frames[1].document.getElementById('status').innerHTML)
}
```

this should come right before triggering `.click()`.