# Clicking Buttons and Evaluating the Resulting Page in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, phantomjs

Having read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621842/phantom-js-fill-fields-click-submit-and-now-stuck-at-accessing-the-next-page), I set up an onLoadFinished function to process a page after form data has been submitted:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();

page.open("http://www.mysite.com/login", function (status) {
  page.includeJs('jquery-1.10.2.min.js', function () {

    //Setup function to handle receiving the response after we click the button
    page.onLoadFinished = function (response) {
      page.includeJs('jquery-1.10.2.min.js', function () {
        var out = page.evaluate(function () {
          //For simplicity, let's say the resulting page contains only one div
          //with the output we want to test.
          return $("div").html();
        });

        //If the term 'Username or Password Incorrect' is on the page, then that
        //means the login failed.
        if(out.search('Username or Password Incorrect') !== -1) {
          console.log("Failed to login when it should have worked.");
        } else {
          console.log("Login succeeded.");
        }
        phantom.exit();
      });
    };

    //This is where we actually load the page for the first time and submit the
    //form data
    page.evaluate(function () {
      $("input[name=username]").val("Sam");
      $("input[name=password]").val("password");
      $("button[type=submit]").click();
    });
  });
});
```

Now, this code works, but it seems to me that I shouldn't have to include the same JS file more than once. But if I include only the first includeJs call (the outtermost one), I get an error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`

Also, if you want to test a lot of button clicks one after the other this way, then you will eventually end up with heavily-nested function calls that will be difficult to manage.

I feel like I'm really confused, and not doing things the correct way. Can someone explain the correct way to click links, submit form data, and evaluate the resulting page in PhantomJS?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this problem. Did you find it?

Comment: No, but decided instead to use CasperJS, which has some better tools for doing this sort of thing. If you're looking to use it specifically in your own NodeJJ instance, you'll need to use the SpookyJS library, as Casper is its own interpreter.